# Скрыть меню выбора вкладок в QTabWidget (PyQT5)

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Необходимо скрыть меню выбора текущей вкладки в *QTabWidget*.
Для того, что бы была возможность переключать вкладки только из кода.
Не должно влиять на содержимое вкладок, вариант временного удаления неактивных вкладок не подойдет.

Подойдут и решения через таблицу стилей, и через код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужна вот эта штука QStackedWidget https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qstackedwidget.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myQTabWidget.tabBar().hide()
```

Закрыто.